# How to Remove Production Track

Tags: google-play, google-play-console

We mistakenly started the production rollout but we have new updates that are required to go to open testing in the Google Play Console.

How can I stop a production rollout? It doesn't seem like I can. I tried discarding a release and that did not work. I tried creating a new release with a new APK and that did not work.

Any ideas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot remove an app from the Play Store without unpublishing it entirely in the Play Console (which would not allow you to push to testing tracks).

Comment: Was secretly hoping this wasn't the case. Thank you for your answer